# Getting payment method issue in magento2.0

Tags: magento2

developing sample application using front end react-native and backend using magneto 2.0 getting payment issue when i was placing the order.

```
Here like i am passing the values and Url 
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/rest/V1/carts/16/order

body passing like this : 
{
 "paymentMethod":{"method": "Cash On Delivery"}
}
```

Issue has :  `"message": "The requested Payment Method is not available.",`

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the Payment method "Cash On Delivery" ?
If not, please enable it by doing this : 
`Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > Cash On Delivery Payment > Enable = Yes`

**P.S:** Please Clear the appropriate Application Caches after the step above.

Furthermore, the bind param is the payment method's code not its name/description.

**P.S:** You should be able to find the payment method "code" in the output of the `{{url}}/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information` end-point.

Good Luck! :)